# Python - Using a dataframe's values to assign names of new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called 'population' that looks like this -

```
Index   Name      Pop
0      Mumbai    100000
1      Delhi    233299
```

...

I want to create dataframes with names 'Mumbai',"Delhi',....
So I coded this -

```
npop = len(population)   #number of popuation centres

    for i in np.arange(0,npop):
        population[i]["Name"] = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-01 00:00:00', freq ='H').tolist(),columns = ['Susceptible','Exposed','Infected','Removed'])  #Create a blank dataframe
        population[i]['Name'][0]['Susceptible'] = population.iloc[i][0]  #Sets Current population to Susceptible
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do is create a blank dataframe with 4 columns and whose index is the datetime range given. I then want to set the pop value of that city to the Susceptible value column's 1st row cell in the new dataframe.

Comment: What's `SetNames`???

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Have edited it now

Answer (score 0):

I believe need fill each DataFrame in loop by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) of column `Name`, finally get `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = {}
for i, x in df.groupby('Name'):
    dfs[i] = pd.DataFrame({'Susceptible': x['Pop'].iloc[0]}, 
                          index = pd.date_range('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-01 00:00:00', freq ='H'),
                columns = ['Susceptible','Exposed','Infected','Removed'])  

#print (dfs)

print (dfs['Mumbai'])
```

EDIT:

If need create first value only:

```
dfs = {}
for i, x in df.groupby('Name'):
    dfs[i] = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-01 00:00:00', freq ='H'),
                columns = ['Susceptible','Exposed','Infected','Removed'])  #Create a blank dataframe
    dfs[i].loc[dfs[i].index[0], 'Susceptible'] = x['Pop'].iloc[0]

print (dfs['Mumbai'].head())
                   Susceptible Exposed Infected Removed
2016-01-01 00:00:00      100000     NaN      NaN     NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00         NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
2016-01-01 02:00:00         NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
2016-01-01 03:00:00         NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00         NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: This created the dataframes, but it assigned the initial population - Pop value to the entire column in Susceptible. I wanted just the first cell of Susceptible to have the Pop value. Thanks!

Comment: @Adeetya - It is possible, but maybe exist some better solution for your problem.

Comment: Need `loc` like `dfs[i].loc[dfs[i].index[0], 'Susceptible']`

Comment: How do I call by datetime value of index?

Comment: @Adeetya - use `dfs['Mumbai'].index[0]`

Comment: How do I index by datetime value like dfs['Mumbai].index[2016-01-01 00:00:00] isn't working?

Comment: @Adeetya - need `dfs['Mumbai].loc['2016-01-01 00:00:00']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172811/discussion-between-adeetya-and-jezrael).